# Onesignal Push Notification cannot show number message on iOS

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I'm building an app with Ionic v3.

Now I've already set up push notification with OneSignal.

But I find out that if I send only 'number' message like '123123', iOS Device cannot receive the message. (Android work perfect). But English, Chinese and any other languages work.

p.s Idk attached link is ok or not, just in case, here's OneSignal plugin link https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs